# Developing on a folder outside the svn local repository structure and copying back

Tags: svn, macos, version-control, repository, osx-snow-leopard

I am using the SVN binary that comes with Mac OS X snow leopard. I am new to SVN and the learning path seems to be steep.

I have a local svn repository(or should i call it folder?) with the traditional structure,

```
+ Tags
   + 0.3
   + 0.3.2
   + 0.3.6 
+ Branches
+ Trunk
   + files.php
   + files.js
   + files.css
   + All other currently working files.
```

But i want to develop in a different folder outside this structure. Once i am done with that, i thought i could copy it's files back to trunk folder and run svn stat->diff->commit. But then sub folders i copied had had "S" as status, that is *switched related to parent directory*. But the files were showing "M" - modified.

What i want to do

**svn/trunk** ==copy=> **outside developing folder** ===Finish==> **svn/trunk(same as 1st)** => **Commit**

I tried to hard link the folder to the trunk directory, but it seems that there is no equivalent "mklink /J" in OS X.

Is there an alternate way to do this?

**Situations**
Developing wordpress plugin, plugin needs to reside in the plugins directory.
Other web applications i am developing.

Wordpress plugin is committed to SVN which is problematic. Second one is private svn server that i use for managing the apps for iOS & Android I'm developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you checkout in svn terminology is called **working copy**.

You don't need to checkout the *whole* svn repository, but rather **trunk** only:

```
 cd desired_location
 svn co path_to_repo/Trunk
```

When you finish the work, you can checkin all changed files.

Comment: Thanks! After i do this, how do i tag the release versions and commit afterwards?

Comment: After finishing, can i do `svn ci -m "message"` on both the repo and this folder _desired_location_? Thanks, you are very helpful.

Comment: You can do all svn actions in your working copy (desired_location in my example) including commit your changes, Committing will post your changes in svn repository and thus will make them public available for other team players using the same code.